# How can I enable php extension in Azure app service -> web app (Linux)

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am trying to do composer install but it needs some php extension to be installed like php-soap

```
besimple/soap-client v0.2.6 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
```

Linux OS is: Debian GNU/Linux 8

So, How can i enable php-soap in azure web app?

Comment: You bake that into your container then bring the container to run on App Service - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/containers/

Comment: I am using Azure php7.0 built-in container!

Comment: Don't. Build you own, you can start with the built-in one as your base: https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/php

Answer (score 2):

Please check [this](https://azureossd.github.io/2019/01/29/azure-app-service-linux-adding-php-extensions/) blog that explain how to install PHP extension on Azure App Service plan on Linux.

Also there is a great document available on how to do this at Microsoft docs link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-php#run-composer).